# get exception when deploying the application on glassfish serve

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

here is the entity bean class

```
package retail.model.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;


import javax.persistence.Column;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
//@TransactionAttribute(value=REQUIRED)

public class Customer  implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5256938732963606407L;
    private int customer_id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email_id;
    private int phNumber;
    private List<Customer> customer;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    public int getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_id(int customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "addres")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "email_add")
    public String getEmail_id() {
        return email_id;
    }

    public void setEmail_id(String email_id) {
        this.email_id = email_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "ph_number")
    public int getPhNumber() {
        return phNumber;
    }

    public void setPhNumber(int phNumber) {
        this.phNumber = phNumber;
    }



     public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
        this.customer = customerList;
    }

    public String validate(){
          if(name!=null && name!=""){
          System.out.println("chandan");
          return "viewCustomerDetails";
          }
          else{
          return "viewCustomerDetails";
          }
          }
}
```

When deploying getting below exception.

```
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : [PersistenceUnit: RetailUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: CUSTOMER, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(customerList)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:464)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What relationship is between Customer and list of customers?

Answer (score 0):

Add mapping to your `customerList`

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Customer.class, mappedBy="mappedFieldInCustomer", fetch=FetchType.LAZY /* or EAGER */) 
public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
   return customer;
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to complete the solution by posting the mapping on the new "mappedFieldInCustomer" property